# How do I unlock more levels in Co-Op?

Tags: portal-2

In Portal 2 Co-op hub there are topics to play in, such as team building and mass and velocity. But how do I unlock all of them? I have absolutly no idea how to get mobility gels and excusion funnels.

Answer (score 4):

Finishing all of the levels in a category will unlock the next one. So in your case, if you finish all of the levels under *Mass and Velocity*, you will unlock *Hard-Light Surfaces*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the levels in standard co-op before it will unlock them in challenge mode co-op.